# socket.io jquery interfering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io on my site, and in order to get it working I need to include my jquery script tag after my socket.io script tag, but doing this breaks my buttons that are using jquery.  If I reverse the order all of my buttons function again, but my socket code no longer does.  If anyone can help me get both working (ideally without removing Jquery usage), I'd very much appreciate it!  Thanks!

```
<html>

<head>

    <link href="/assets/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">    <link rel="icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"      crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>  <div class="header">        <a href="/" id="header-title">smashbet.gg</a>

        <% if (!locals.user) { %>           <form method="POST" action="/login" id="login">
                Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username"></input>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password"></input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remember Me">
                <input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Login"></input>
                            </form>             <% }else { %>

                <form method="POST" action="/logout" id="logout">
                    <a href="/account/<%= user.username %>" id="welcomeUser">Welcome <%= user.username %></a>
                    <input type="submit" value="Logout"></input>
                </form>
                <% } %>     </div>



    <div class="column-left">       <img src="/assets/images/smashbet1_15.png"></img>

        <% if (!locals.user) { %>           <a href="#openModal" id="signupButton">Signup!</a>          </br>

            <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <h2>Sign up!</h2>

                    <form method="POST" action="/signup" id="signup">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <span id='message'></span>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" onkeyup='check();' />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Confirm Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" onkeyup='check();' />
                        </div><br />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>

                </div>          </div>

            <% } %>

                <% if (locals.tourneyList) {            for(var i = 0; i < locals.tourneyList.length; i++) { %>
                    <div class="tourneyLink">
                        <a href="/tournament/<%= tourneyList[i].link %>">

                            <%= locals.tourneyList[i].name %>


                        </a>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <% } } %>   </div>

    <div class="column-center">         <iframe src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=<%= tourneyLink %>" height="740" width="1310" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"       allowfullscreen="true">        </iframe>

        <div class="bet-area">

            <form method="POST" action="/bet" id="placeBet">
                <% if (locals.user) { %>
                    <p>Total Funds: $
                        <%= user.wallet %>
                    </p>



                    <p id="currentBet">Current Bet: $
                        <%= user.bet %>
                            <% if(user.player !== "") { %>on
                                <%= user.player %>
                                    <% } %>
                    </p>

                    Bet: <input type="number" name="bet" min="1" max="<%= user.wallet %>">
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <button type="submit" value="Player 1" name="placeBetButton" id="placeBetButton1">Player 1</button>
                    <button type="submit" value="Player 2" name="placeBetButton">Player 2</button>

                    <% } %>             </form>

        </div>  </div>

    <div class="column-right">      <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://www.twitch.tv/<%= tourneyLink %>/chat" height="925" width="305">         </iframe>   </div>

    <br />

    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>   <script>        $(document).on('submit', '#placeBet', function (e) {            e.preventDefault();             $.post('/bet', $(this).serialize() + '&' + $.param({ placeBetButton: $(document.activeElement).val(), tourneyLink: '<%= tourneyLink %>' }),
                function (data) {

                    $('#currentBet').html("Current bet: $" + data.bet + " on " + data.player);

                    // 'data' contains the response from the request
                }).error(function () {

                });

            return false;       });


        var check = function () {           if (document.getElementById('password').value == document.getElementById('confirmPassword').value) {
                document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'cyan';
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Passwords Match!';          } else {
                document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'yellow';
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Passwords Don\'t Match';            }       }   </script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    <script>        $(function () {             var socket = io();          socket.on('test message', function(msg) {
                $('#placeBetButton1').html(msg);
            });             $('form').submit(function () {
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;           });         });

    </script> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I should have specified, I know I'm including Jquery twice at the moment, it is broken differently depending on which I remove.

Comment: obviously, you have to include jquery before you use it. so, do that, first and foremost. no other option will work. there's no reason to even consider any other option.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by interfering? In what way is it interfering? (it ain't workin isn't good enough. Why isn't it working?)

Comment: When I add socket.io (first) all buttons on the page no longer function.  They're all submit buttons that I handle in node middleware, but they do absolutely nothing when clicked.

I guess I need to focus on the socket not working when added after Jquery though from the sound of it.

Comment: Why don't they function? does the event not fire? does something inside the handler throw an error? do some debugging.

Comment: The event doesn't fire*  Sorry this is my first post here and I'm still getting used to things.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct order of including your js/libraries/frameworks would be:

1. Socket
2. jQuery
3. bootstrap.min.js
4. app.js (i guess here are your own scripts)
5. If you reaaally must, your inlinescripts(shouldn't they be in app.js?)